# RecordNotFound Can't find Event without ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a lot of trouble trying to pass an id from a model into a different controller. I've read similar posts and tried different solutions, but can't seem to pass the Event id into the Invitations controller.

*UPDATE*

The goal is that a user, while looking at an event they created, will click on an Invite link. This link needs to save the ID from the Event it came from so that Invitations can be associated with that event.

In my models, I for the Event model, I have 'has_many "invitations' and for the Invitation model I have 'belongs_to :events'

Here is my code.

show.html.erb within my Events folder:

```
<%= link_to 'Invite guests', invitations_path(:event => @event.id) %>
```

This link maps to 'invitations#new':

```
<% provide(:title, 'Invite Guests') %>
<h1>Invite your guests</h1>

   <%= form_for(@invitation) do |f| %>

     <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

       <%= f.label :name %>
       <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Name" %> <br>

       <%= f.label :email %>
       <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %> <br>

    <%= f.submit "Send" %>
```

InvitationsController:

```
def index
end

def new
    @invitation = Invitation.new
end

def create
    user = current_user.events.find(params[:event])
    @invitation = user.invitations.build(params[:invitation])

    if @invitation.save
              flash[:success] = "Invitations sent!"
        redirect_to user
    else
        render '/home'
    end
end
```

I know that if I replace:

```
    user = current_user.events.find(params[:event])
```

with:

```
    user = current_user.events.find(1)
```

Routes:

```
resources :users
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :events, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
resources :invitations, only: [:new, :create]

root to: '/home'

match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete


match '/events', to: 'events#new'
match '/invitations', to: 'invitations#new'
```

Everything works fine, but of course, this is not suitable since I am hard coding the Event ID. I am pretty new to RoR (about 2 months of experience) so there may be a more efficient way to do this. So any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to 'Invite guests', invitations_path(:event => @event.id) %>
```

Goes to:

```
def index
```

Not to:

```
def create
```

If you want to go to `create` do:

```
<%= link_to 'Invite guests', invitations_path(:event => @event.id), method: :post %>
```

Comment: Hi juanpastas, thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, I left out some detail. See my updated post + new code. Essentially, I cannot use the method post since the invitations_path leads to another form that allows one to invite their guests. These guests get stored in a table that belongs to Events. Perhaps my code is not the best way to achieve this? Any direction to the right solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: could you show your routes? invitations_path should go to index even if you pass parameters to it.

Comment: routes added to main post. I also added the index method to the controller, but it does not have any code in it.

Comment: I would use standard routes: delete `match '/invitations', to: 'invitations#new'` and use `resources :invitations`

Comment: After using standard routes, I now get a "Missing template invitations/index" error. I in fact do not have an index.html.erb for invitations. Does this mean I have to create an intermediary page (the index page) in order to capture the event id? Thanks.

Comment: you don't have `app/views/invitations/index.html.erb` file

Comment: Exactly. As I pointed out, does this mean I have create an intermediary page that when will link to `def create` ? I guess I am not sure what kind of code will be in invitations/index.html.erb? Thanks again for helping me through this!

Comment: Is not needed, if you want to got to create directly you can use link_to with method post

Comment: but you have to use standard routes: resources :invitations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to include `code` method: :post `code` However, it seems like it I am skipping my `code` invitations/new.html.erb `code` page and getting redirected to /home.. which makes sense since I am not saving a name or email to the database.

Comment: hehe, you don't have to put \`code\` before printing code, just use backquote your actual code backquote.

Comment: haha, I was able to do it before. But the code I wanted to post is simply between the two "codes". So above, it should be `method: :post` and `invitations/new.html.erb`